# How to save String[] persistantly?

Tags: android

I am trying to save

```
public   String [] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl,imageUrl2,imageUrl3,imageUrl4};
```

Persistantly.

I want to save the variables inside the array list, to a persistant storage so when the app is killed or destroyed. the URL's are still availible. But the url's will change about every month. I dont want to keep building up strings in a database over time.

So whats the best way to go about doing this?

EDIT: Something like...

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.v("onSavedInstanceState", "Saved inside the bundle");
        SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("URL1", imageUrl);
        editor.putString("URL2", imageUrl2)

    }
```

Comment: It depends on what version of the API you're using. Pretty much you're stuck using a SQLite database as SharedPreference is only good for primitives, unless you want to do a CSV type in a String.

Comment: What do you mean its only good for primitives?

Comment: Primitives mean simple data types such as Strings, ints, booleans etc. But you don't need to store your array in a single field, keep going with the idea you've introduced in your code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of data  storage options available for Android, [see list of options and overview here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), with the simplest one being **Shared Preferences**. If you're just going to keep a handful of URLs around this is probably your best bet. The cleanup is up to you but can be very simple with a proper key/value pair naming strategy.

E.g.:

```
"URL1", "google.com"
"URL2", "stackoverflow.com"
...
"URLn", "nthwebsite.com"
```

where the keys (URLn) would remain the same but the web pages changed as necessary.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how i would save the string[] in my question to a shared preference, pull the info from it, and do clean-up when the url's change?

Comment: Is there an example of using the share preferences that gives information about it and using it?

Comment: Such as writing to it, and pulling the information from it and setting it the the String[]. Or maybe you could put that in your answer

Comment: You're asking for a lot of code. The thing is, each of those parts are pretty simple on their own. The API is for SharedPreferences is pretty straightforward and the logic of how to update is up to you. Don't use Stinrg[], use a Vector collection: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: And I should use another Collection? Why do you say this?

Comment: I think what you suggested should do the trick. in onSavedInstanceState() the URls are store to shared preference, when it is restored in onCreate, ill pull them out, and set them to there String variables. Hows that sound?

Comment: `String[]` is just as type safe as `Vector<String>` (which should probably be `List<String>`...)

Answer (score 2):

Save it in the application's SQLite instance, and manually clean up or  overwrite old URLs.

Comment: How would i go about doing the manual clean up? And how would the app know when the url's change and, how to overrwrite the URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can save it to SharedPreference if you do not want to use DB